# Understanding recursive relationship in nhibernate mapping

Tags: c#, nhibernate, domain-driven-design

Let's say that I have one entity Page like this

```
public class Page
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public string Title {get; set;}
   public string Body {get; set;}
   ... to do
}
```

now I want to add functionality that one `Page` can have one or more `Page` or One or more pages can belong to one parent `Page`.

How would you do that and how would you map (using nhibernate) this Page entity with this requirement in mind?

Any type of mapping is fine (fluent, by code, ...).

If you need more information please ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this with **FluentNhibernate**

```
References(x => x.ParentCategory).Column("ParentCategoryId").Cascade.SaveUpdate();
HasMany<Category>(x => x.ChildCategories).KeyColumn("ParentCategoryId").Cascade.SaveUpdate();
```

I have a class `Category` with childs and one parent.

```
public class Category : Entity<long>
{
    public virtual IList<Category> ChildCategories
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual Category ParentCategory
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make them self-reference.. somewhat like this:

```
Page
----
Id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY
Title VARCHAR(50)
Body VARCHAR(500)
ParentId INT
```

Then, in Fluent, you would have something like this:

```
public class Page {
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual string Body { get; set; }
    public virtual Page Parent { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Page> Children { get; set; }
}

public class PageClassMap : ClassMap<Page> {
    public PageClassMap() {
        Table("Page");
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
        Map(x => x.Title);
        Map(x => x.Body);
        References(x => x.Parent);
        HasMany(x => x.Children).KeyColumn("ParentId");
    }
}
```